# Send notification to user after a while Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2, cron-task

I have this scenario: A user buys a product and when two days have passed after the transaction has been processed, I need to send a mail notification to buyer.

At this moment my idea is to use [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) and check build a cron job to check in each day and if 2 days have passed and if true, cron job will send mail notification.

I don't know if is ok to do this... Can you give me better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ActiveJob](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activejob) with `perform_later`, like:

```
NotificationSendJob.set(wait: 2.days).perform_later(record)
```

Note that not all backends support this. You can see check feature matrix here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html

Answer (score 1):

Rather that using whenever,I  would suggest using sidekiq which is a background processing library. The cron job has to be executed everyday(in your particular case). It doesn't consider whether a mail has to be sent or not. The job will still be executed even if no mails are to be sent, which is a wrong approach.

You can use a background processing library like sidekiq to schedule the job in the background. checkout https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks!